# mysql remote management

Tags: mysql

I want to use MySQL Administrator and MySQL Query Browser on a remote mysql server.

Should I just change the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 to accept all connections or is there a more secure way.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like more of a serverfault-type question. If you ask it there, you're more likely to get an answer: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you connect to your database server using Putty and establish an SSH tunnel connection, once you have a tunnel established then you can connect to your database server from MySQL Tools, HeidiSQL or other programs.

Read this http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html page for instructions on how to configure.

Comment: This sounds like the best solution for making a secure connection with minimal configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To set `bind-address` is for your server IP, not remote IP.

To set up a remote connection, you set your `bind-address` in `my.cnf` to your server IP. You then grant access to a remote IP address.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

If you have a firewall installed, make sure to open up port 3306 to accept incoming connections.

Comment: source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score 0):

I would go with meme's answer and add a local tunnel:
Source port: 3307
Destination: localhost:3306
Then I personal like to use a SQL GUI called SQLyog.
And use:
Server: localhost
Port: 3307
And obviously your username/password

But, that is assuming that you can SSH into your server. If you can't then the paid version of SQLyog has a PHP tunnel script (very cool!) or just install phpMyAdmin or some other variation there of.